# What "flavour" of Argon2 is used by python module argon2-cffi?

Tags: python, argon2-cffi

Argon2 v1.3 is the algorithm used by python module `argon2-cffi`.

In the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/) they state the following:

> "argon2-cffi implements Argon2 version 1.3, as described in in: [Argon2: the memory-hard function for
> password hashing and other applications](https://www.cryptolux.org/images/0/0d/Argon2.pdf)."

Yet this document does not specify the actual use of any "flavour" (i/d/id), it just explains the differences.

What "flavour" is used by `argon2-cffi` by default? Is there a way to specify the "flavour" you want to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the return value of the `hash` function in class `PasswordHasher` from `argon2-cffi`, it appears it can be concluded that the hybrid "flavour" is used by default.

```
from argon2 import PasswordHasher

PasswordHasher().hash("foo")
```

Returns:

```
"$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=4$xIu1KPUI7Ofe6HxYhmbNiA$6q7HjVOe6933Ogaw0f7pLodCdBgJsST8JAszTkv4Jh4"
```

This is confirmed by the comment in said class:

> Uses Argon2\ **id** by default and always uses a random salt_ for hashing.
> But it can verify any type of *Argon2* as long as the hash is correctly
> encoded.

Changing the "flavour" used by the module is done by assigning the variable `type` of class `PasswordHasher` to a `Type` class defined in  like so:

```
from argon2 import PasswordHasher, Type
```

```
PasswordHasher(type=Type.I).hash("foo")  # lib.Argon2_i
```

```
PasswordHasher(type=Type.D).hash("foo")  # lib.Argon2_d
```

```
PasswordHasher(type=Type.ID).hash("foo") # lib.Argon2_id
```

Each of these `Type` variables reference a corresponding argon2 library, shown in comments.